# how can I access editText value in class which extends listactivity in android

Tags: android

I want to access values entered using editText in class which extends ListActivity.
I am not able to use findviewbyid method to access editText. Which method should I use? Can somebody help me

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to use findviewbyid"? Any restriction? You can always use the method to find the view and retrieve data from it.

Comment: is your editText in one listItem? Is it what you mean??

Comment: maybe you are not able to pass context in your adapter view which you have bind to the listview.

Comment: Please post logcat and some snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your EditText is in custom view of your list item if yes then try something like this :

```
View oView = LayoutInflater..inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null); 
EditText yourEditText = (EditText)oView.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id_from_xml_file);
String editTextValue = yourEditText.getText().toString();
```